# SpeechSynthesis.getVoices() always retuns zero on Debian + ARM + Chromium

Tags: javascript, linux, chromium, speech

I'm running Chromium 63.0 on Debian 9.3 (32 bit) on an ARM board (ASUS Tinker board).

The call to SpeechSynthesis.getVoice() function always returns an empty array.

I directly called the function and returned empty array.

I added the callback function:

```
if (typeof speechSynthesis !== 'undefined' && speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
   console.log("Set callback function ..")
   speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = populateVoiceList;
}
```

but again it returned empty array. I see the console.log output so the members should be supported.

Of course no sounds are generated by speak() function, even if I run the minimal:

```
speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Ciao'))
```

I run the browser with the **--enable-speech-dispatcher** option and the browser said that it is not supported. Should it be supported since version 33 ???